# Intellij Idea compiler recompiles already compiled project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use maven command which cleans,builds whole project, creates war and deploys to server. I cannot use Intellij to do that since I have only Community edition. It builds the project in same directory as intellij.

To speed things up I wrote a script which finds compiled files in local "target" directory which are newer than the ones in server and copy them. It all works okay but the problem is Intellij does not see classes compiled with maven as the ones it should skip and rebuilds whole project all over.

Currently it works like this:

1. Manually in terminal build whole project with maven
2. Go back to intellij -> make project
3. Rebuilds all
4. Run script -> it swaps all files

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Manually in termin build whole project with maven
2. Go back to intellij. Change one file -> make project
3. Compiles only one java file
4. Run script -> it swaps only one .class file

So the problem is how do I make intellij treat files already compiled with external tool as compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. IntelliJ IDEA has its own incremental compilation system which tracks the dependencies between files being compiled and recompiles the minimum set of classes for every set of changes. External compilation with tools like Maven or Gradle does not update IntelliJ IDEA's incremental compilation database. Because of that, IntelliJ IDEA cannot recognize the fact that classes have been already compiled with an external tool, and will recompile.

Comment: If IDEA's own incremental compilation system generated all the class files already, why would it not be possible to launch the application using those already generated class files. Why does the Run or Debug function have to go through the whole paint of building it yet again? I have an application that takes like 30 seconds to finally start, and it's very annoying. I use dcevm that helps me apply changing to a running program, but for programs that I have to restart, it takes too long to start them.
Would it be possible to find the .class directory and add it to the build classpath maybe?

Comment: Once again: the Run or Debug function needs to ensure that your classes are up to date, and it cannot recognize the fact that classes have been already compiled with an external tool.

Comment: I don't use an external tool to compile, and I void things like gradle and maven like the plague.

Comment: Then the problem you're facing is entirely unrelated to what the question is about.

Comment: I disagree. The IDE is managing the compilations continuously. It should know instantly what Java files need to be compiled still, if any, in order to launch an application that you're working on quickly. If you want to use an external tool like Gradle, Maven, Ant, or something else, that's the only time were you should be facing having to compile the whole set of source files upon launching.
IDEA should be optimized to handle this better. It would save time. We're talking launching a JVM on a set of already available classes plus resources in a classpath here. This should be (made) possible.

Comment: I tried auto making in the background, but that makes it even worse, because once a make is underway and you make additional code changes, it has to run a make after finishing the previous make, and I'm not sure if it's even properly canceling the previous make. The question is do new class files appear in a directory somewhere while editing - without enabling the auto make feature? If so, why not be able to point the classpath to it, and have the IntelliJ guys add a quick fixer upper semi build feature to get a launch going almost instantly?

Comment: The question was about duplicate compilation when using Maven from the command line. If you're using IDEA's built-in make functionality, then yes, it does know what files it needs to recompile, and does recompile only those files. If this doesn't work for you, then you should contact the support team or ask another question here to investigate why. But, once again, this is not what the original question was about.

Comment: While editing, IntelliJ IDEA does not generate any class files. The editor highlighting does not use any Java compiler and does not generate any Java bytecode.

Comment: The interest is quicker launch times. The person might be using Maven, but perhaps that person could try to use both the internal IDE compilation cycles, and Maven if he so pleases. I think we're all interested in boosting productivity, are we not?
You're right about IDEA not putting out class files as you're editing files. I incorrectly assumed that it does.
Are there any ways at all to properly incrementally compile Java classes in IDEA?

Comment: Searching for idea and incremental compilation I'm seeing all kinds of articles and forums and people being excited about it. There is mention of things being faster. But I have as of yet to see any "incremental" compilation in idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

That troubled me for long time. Finally, i found this .
[IDEA build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n611y.png)
You can choose whether use InteliJ or gradle to compile when runnning program. Under gradle project, it uses gradle to build by default.